# Xcode 7.0 and 7.1, code coverage turned ON, unit test crash "cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag"

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage, xcode7

We have been having this problem since **Xcode 7 beta** and the problem persists to this day with **Xcode 7.1**.

Basically we cannot turn ON code coverage in Xcode.  In Xcode 6, this worked fine, but has been broken ever since Xcode 7.  At the end of a unit test run, we get infinite console output saying:

```
profiling: /Users/<my path to app>/ObjectiveC.gcda: cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag (<some hex address>)
```

This output repeats until the app **crashes**.  I just have no idea why this is happening and all attempts to fix this issue have failed (except for turning off instrumenting program flows and turning off code coverage).  I even tried setting up a build phase run script that finds and clears the previous code coverage files, but that did not work either.

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [@gagarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1425567/gagarwal) for the direction.  I'll just have to figure out a different jenkins reporting tool since the old code coverage files were needed, but I suppose that isn't supported anymore.  Here are some screenshots to illustrate the setup that generates code coverage reports viewable within Xcode based on gagarwal's sugguestions:

```
----------------------        
main app target config
----------------------
```

[image]
[image]

```
----------------------
test app target config
----------------------
```

[image]
[image]

```
------------------------------------------
Scheme config (see "Gather coverage data")
------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7's new code coverage features use the [LLVM coverage format](http://llvm.org/docs/CoverageMappingFormat.html).

Also Xcode 7 has new build settings for code coverage:
"CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE"

Make sure "CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE" is set to "YES" and following to NO:

GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES = NO;
GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO;

Comment: thanks @gagarwal.  I answered my own Q so that I could add the screenshots.